# Генерация POJO классов из из схемы данных в виде файла .xml?

Tags: java, база-данных, xml, pojo

Kак можно cгенерировать POJO классы из схемы данных в виде файла .xml?

В какую сторону копать?

Comment: вот это посмотрите https://github.com/highsource/hyperjaxb3/wiki/Reference_-_single_page#Reference-singlepage-GeneratingORMmetadata

Answer (score 0, accepted):

xml оказался нетипичным, пришлось парсить через JDOM

Answer (score 0):

У Hibernate есть библиотека для генерации POJO из конфигурации xml. Читайте [здесь](https://docs.jboss.org/tools/latest/en/hibernatetools/html/codegen.html).

> При использовании тега `<hbm2java>` или плагина Eclipse для генерации кода POJO Java

Или [здесь](https://docs.jboss.org/tools/latest/en/hibernatetools/html/ant.html#d0e4821).

> `<hbm2java>` - генератор кода Java. Параметры для контроля использования синтаксиса JDK 5 и возможность аннотации POJO с помощью аннотаций EJB3 / Hibernate.

Где взять? Смотри [тут](http://www.jboss.org/tools/download).